# Align two panels next to eachother

Tags: java, swing, alignment, jpanel, layout-manager

I am currently trying to create a script editor. But the lineNumber `JPanel` is not top aligned next to the `JTextArea`. The lineNumber `JPanel` appears at the center on the right side of the `JTextArea`.

It looks like this:

[image]

This is the class which instantiates both of these components:

```
private ScriptEditor() {

    ((FlowLayout) this.getLayout()).setVgap(0);
    ((FlowLayout) this.getLayout()).setHgap(0);

    //This is the lineNumber JPanel which has no LayoutManager set.
    lineNumPanel = new LineNumberPanel();

    //I tried setAlignmentY but it did not work
    lineNumPanel.setAlignmentY(TOP_ALIGNMENT);

    //The text area.
    scriptArea = new JTextArea(22,15);
    scriptArea.setFont(new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.PLAIN, 15));
    scriptArea.setMargin(new Insets(3, 10, 3, 10));


    //This JPanel contains the two components: lineNumber JPanel and the JTextArea
    JPanel temp = new JPanel();
    temp.add(lineNumPanel);
    temp.add(scriptArea);

    //Set the scrollPane
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(temp);
    scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));

    //Add the scrollPane to this JPanel.
    add(scrollPane);
}
```

Comment: Why not use some alreayd made code editor textarea, like RSyntaxTextArea? It's easy to work with and will be better than anything you do this way.

Answer (score 1):

```
JPanel temp = new JPanel();
```

By default a JPanel uses a FlowLayout. a FlowLayout vertically centers the components added to the panel. If you don't like this behaviour then try a different layout manager like a horizontal [BoxLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html), which will allow you to align the component at the top/center/bottom depending on the components vertical alignment.

However, using a JPanel is not the best approach. Instead you should be adding the line number component to the `row header` of the scroll pane. See [Text Component Line Number](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/23/text-component-line-number/) for an example of this approach.